# Check each row in a groupby against all rows in that groupby while creating new variable

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,1], 'Year': [2007, 2008, 2010,2011], 'Program': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A']})


ID  Year    Program
0   1   2007    A
1   1   2008    B
2   1   2010    A
3   1   2011    A
```

I'd like to `groupby` **ID** and **Year** and then for each row within that group create a new variable **Any**, check whether the next year exists. If that year+1 exists then it should be **1** and if it does not, it should be **0**, and the final row, should be **Nan**:

```
ID  Year    Program Any
0   1   2007    A   1.0
1   1   2008    B   0.0
2   1   2010    A   1.0
3   1   2011    A   NaN
```

I apologize that I do not have any 'what I've tried'. Once I've gotten past using `groupby`, I cannot figure out how to access the entire groups data while assigning values to each individual row.

Comment: If you `groupby` by `ID` and `Year` you will get one row per group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pair `ID, Year` are unique, a merge on `ID, Year` would work:

```
s = df.merge(df.assign(Year=df['Year'].sub(1),
                       dummy=1), on=['ID','Year'],
        how='left')['dummy']

df['Any'] = s.fillna(0)
```

Output,  note that the largest year also filled with `0`:

```
   ID  Year Program  Any
0   1  2007       A  1.0
1   1  2008       B  0.0
2   1  2010       A  1.0
3   1  2011       A  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with `groupby` + `diff`

```
s=df.groupby('ID')['Year'].diff(-1)
s[s.notnull()]=s.eq(-1).astype(int)
s
Out[209]: 
0    1.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
Name: Year, dtype: float64
df['Any']=s
```

Comment: This, similar to my answer, only works when the years are unique within `ID`. A transform/map in general case maybe?